# Box2D static library project installation issues

Tags: c++, header, project, hyperlink, static-libraries

Hey so i just took the following steps:

- Downloaded Box2d 2.1.2 and used cmake to build the msVS++ projectiles
- Built Box2D.sln under debug and release, but didn't touch the libs or dlls
- Made a new Win32 project, and copied the code from "Hello World" which was included in the Box2D download into my new projects main source file
- Added an include directory to the same source code used by Cmake to generate the projects
- Added the project "Box2D" **(the static library project)** to the sollution so i could modify the library's code; generated by cMake
- Added "Box2D" as a refrence under my new projects common properties
- Looked at "Box2D"'s librarian properties and set 'link library dependencies' to YES
- **Pondered the question i put as a comment above the includes (please answer that too!)**

Here's Hello World.cpp (please answer the question in the comment)

```
/* I've also added the "Box2D" project generated by cmake, which includes 
    all the same files that are in folder my include directory points to, so i could alter the code.
    Does this mean i should change <Box2D\Box2D.h> to just "Box2D.h" ?  */
#include <Box2D\Box2D.h>
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    B2_NOT_USED(argc);
    B2_NOT_USED(argv);

    // Define the gravity vector.
    b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f);

    // Do we want to let bodies sleep?
    bool doSleep = true;

         // blah blah, rest of code doesn't matter
}
```

However when trying to run this i get errors such as

```
1>c:\libraries and headers\box2d_v2.1.2\box2d_v2.1.2\box2d\build\box2d helloworld\box2d helloworld\box2d helloworld.cpp(30): error C3861: 'B2_NOT_USED': identifier not found
```

which are all about undefined identifiers which ARE defined in the many headers included in Box2D.h. **Why doesn't it see them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: didn't see the *warning* saying that Box2D.h was skipped because it was placed **before stafx.h; so i switched the order of the includes.**